# CookieContainer returns empty

Tags: c#

Hello Everyone i have the follow code

```
        Uri site = new Uri("http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Solicitacao2.asp");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

        //Console.WriteLine(cookies.GetCookieHeader(site));

        //Get the response and print out the cookies again
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cookies.GetCookieHeader(site));
        }

        Console.Write("end");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Well this code returns the Cookie OK but if i change the URI to http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx it's not show correctly it's return empty

Anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'd expect the change from www to www8 to mean that you get back an empty cookie collection. If you set the cookie at receita.fazenda.gov.br that should work

Answer (score 0):

The server at the new URL does not attempt to set any cookies, so of course no cookies are in the container. Modify your ASP code to set a cookie and it will work.

Comment: Yes it have if i open with a browser chrome it show's the cookie

Comment: There are no cookie headers in the response sent to my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your cookie: `, domain=.receita.fazenda.gov.br`. This says that your cookie can be used with any sub-domain of `receita.fazenda.gov.br`. Have a look at the RFC on cookies or use this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) article.

**UPDATE:** Re-reading your OP, there may be a few things that could be going awry.

One thing is that the site is not setting a cookie when making a request for `www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br` (as mentioned by others). Or, the site did not set the `domain` field of the cookie sent with the response for the request to `www.receita.fazenda.gov.br`. I think it's likely the former—the cookie is not being set by the web server when the request is being made.

Another thing is perhaps you forgot to request the cookie header for the correct site?? Above, you have a line of code that reads `Console.WriteLine(cookies.GetCookieHeader(site));`, where `site` is hardcoded to a `System.Uri` that is different from `www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br`. If that's the case, then you are requesting cookies for a different site than the one for which the request was made.

Comment: Hello but i dont' have a cookie how should i do this ? since i'm trying to get the cookie from my request